# A lot of backup questions, duplicate or improve title?

Tags: discussion, exact-duplicates

Look at [Need a hassle-free backup solution for Windows — needs to be bootable](https://superuser.com/questions/183637/need-a-hassle-free-backup-solution-for-windows-needs-to-be-bootable).

Also, look at its related questions, some of them are closed because they are a duplicate.

Should this be considered a duplicate or should the title be improved to reflect this specific request?

Comment: If your interested: http://superuser.com/tags/backup/info

Comment: Yeah, but can't do anything to that page... I could still suggest a wiki but no time for that at the moment. :-)

Comment: Just wait until you finish your exams then ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If the answers in the original question didn't answer his question, he should add details that make his question distinctly different, that way it's no longer a duplicate

I suggest you start creating an awesome tag wiki for backup solutions, that way at least it will be easier for people to spot them.

Comment: There should be a better way of highlighting tag wiki.

Comment: Make a suggestion on MSO ;-)